# legend overlapping plot area in seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

[image]

I made the plot above using seaborn but I am not able to place the legend outside plot properly. Please note that the legend is cut off on the right side of the image. This is how it looks in real, I did not cut it manually. This is the code I am using:

```
sns.lineplot(x="Time", y='Anomaly', style='country', hue='region', size='area', sizes=(1., 4), data=df)
# Put the legend out of the figure
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.2)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(.95, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

-- EDIT:

here is a data to replicate this issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4gd447e22zb5yk/subset.csv?dl=0

Comment: For a detailed guide on how to place the legend out of the plot, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132). Here you place the legend at 95% of the axes size. However for it to be outside the axes, you need to use 100% or more. Hence `bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)` or even `(1.02, 1)` might be a good idea.

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, when I do 1.05 the legend is no longer even visible

Comment: That's why I marked this as duplicate. In particular, the "Postprocessing" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132) explains possible solutions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, even after doing post-processing e.g. subplots_adjust, the legend is partly invisible

Comment: So if you used e.g. `subplots_adjust(right=0.8)` and the legend is still partially hidden, you will want to try `right=0.7` next and see what happens until you're satisfied. If you find yourself in need of values lower than 0.5, you may consider using shorter labels in the legend or increasing the figure width.

Comment: I tried `subplots_adjust(right=0.3)` and still same results. Not sure why that is happening

Comment: If you see no visual difference between using `right=0.3` and `right=0.8` you are not operating on the figure you show. Of course you can provide a [mcve], such that one has a change of helping here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for the feedback, I have added data and updated the code to show what I am doing

Comment: It does not make sense to call `tight_layout` after setting the subplot parameters; it will simply overwrite the previously set parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not specified a sample set for us to be able to test the implementation and generate the plot, but with a toy initialization, modifying `bbox_to_anchor` seems to do the trick. See [matplotlib's legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).

`bbox_to_anchor` controls manual legend placement. Setting it to `(1,1)` places it in the top right corner.

```
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

**Sample plot** with modification:
[image]